# To check a class or an interface implements or extends a particular interface

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

I would like to get all the classes or interfaces that implements or extends the Externalizable interface. For the same I used

Externalizable.class.isAssignableFrom(clasz)

But my intention is to get only the classes or interfaces that implements or extends Externalizable. I do not need clasz if Externalizable is not a superclass or superinterface of  at the **first level**. It would be great if someone could help me with a solution.

Comment: You already have it, besides the fact that it will evaluate to true for Externalizable itself. What makes you think your statement will evaluate to true for a superclass or super interface of Externalizable? Seems like you've reversed the meaning of [the isAssignableFrom() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)).

Comment: Suppose i have an interface A that extends Externalizable and a class B that implements A . Then what i need is only the interface A as the result and I do not need class B in the results.

Comment: So you want only direct (first-tier) descendents of Externalizable?

Comment: yes exactly..!!! Is there any method to get the same?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want only classes and interfaces which directly implement `Externalizable`.

```
Class<?>[] interfaces = clasz.getInterfaces();
for (Class<?> c: interfaces) {
    if (c.equals(Externalizable.class)) {
        // clasz is a direct descendent of Externalizable
    }
}
```

If you just need to know the implementors in Java standard edition, they're listed in the [Externalizable javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html).